# Does Web of Sciences indexation implies a JCR impact factor for a journal?

Tags: journals, bibliometrics, web-of-science

Does an indexation of a journal to the Web of Sciences means that it must have a JCR impact factor?

JCR = Journal Citation Report

Comment: Impact factors require a two year history.

Comment: Suppose it has.

Answer (score 1):

Not just a mere Web of Science indexing. Within Web of Science, there are subgroups and it should be under SSCI or SCI or SCIE, inorder to have an Impact factor score.

For example, journals indexed in Web of Science, but under ESCI group, do not have an impact factor score.